# Spring boot API and React js running on Tomcat

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring-boot, rest

I'm developing a React JS application that fetches all data from my Spring boot API.

Everything works well locally.(Spring boot API on PORT 4000 and React JS on PORT 3000 with a proxy of value "http://localhost/4000")

I managed to create a war file that includes both my React js app and Spring boot API.(Running on PORT 8080)

I deployed the war file on a local tomcat server  with an "ok" status.

Api calls works very well (http://localhost:8080/webfolder/api/categories for instance)

but my React App fails to make api calls correctly (http://localhost:8080/api/categories which it should be http://localhost:8080/webfolder/api/categories) as you can see in the following image:

[image: here]

this is how my pom.xml look like :

```
<groupId>com.fox</groupId>
<artifactId>events-platform</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>events-platform</name>
<description>Events-platform built using React JS and Spring boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-agroal</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.21.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/front-end</workingDirectory>
                <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <nodeVersion>v14.5.0</nodeVersion>
                        <npmVersion>6.14.5</npmVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>npm install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>install</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>npm run build</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>run build</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <copy todir="${project.build.directory}/classes/public">
                                <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/front-end/build"/>
                            </copy>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And this is how the beginning of my package.json look like :

[image: package.json]

Instance of my API calls in the front-end :

[image: api_call]

Comment: how do you do the API calls in your ReactJS client? Can you please add the code?

Comment: @RenatoBack Sure, question updated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you've shown in your tests, your API is using the `/webfolder` context, while your ReactJS client is using the root context `/`.

You could change our client to use the `/webfolder` context, or configure your API to use the root context `/`.

**UPDATE 2020-10-08 - 12:20**

After your update with your web client's sample code, I'd suggest you change your `axios` calls to something like:

```js
const API_ROOT = '/webfolder/api'

useEffect(() => {
  axios.get(`${API_ROOT}/spaces`).then(...).catch(...)
  axios.get(`${API_ROOT}/categories`).then(...).catch(...)
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, that's exactly what I was failing to achieve, I tried to add **"homepage" : http://localhost:8080/webfolder** in my package.json, but it doesn't seem to work, any ideas how to achieve that ?

Comment: @LoutfiAliluch Feel free to accept the answer, then :-)